# Are there specific optimizations for the Ubuntu Server kernel?

Tags: kernel

I liked to install Debian using the netinst images, which installed a base system and allowed me to install additional packages as I wanted. I have searched for something similar in Ubuntu, and the Ubuntu Server images are very similar to Debian netinst, at least I have not noticed any difference.

But today I was struggling with my desktop freezing with heavy I/O operations, and while searching for a solution, I have found that the default disk scheduler is set to `deadline`, which is a better choice for servers, but is probably a bad choice on a desktop. The problem seems to have been solved by setting it to `cfq`. I don't know what is the default scheduler for Ubuntu Desktop, though.

Does the Ubuntu Server kernel receive specific optimizations for servers? Wouldn't installing the package `ubuntu-desktop` on a Ubuntu Server result in an identical system as Ubuntu Desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq#Which_kernel_versions_or_types_are_available_on_the_Ubuntu_Server_CD.3F

> What's the difference between the kernels linux-image-server and
>   linux-image-generic? What architecture is linux-image-server? Which
>   one should I use?
>
> Note: Since 12.04, there is no difference in kernel between Ubuntu
>   Desktop and Ubuntu Server since linux-image-server is merged into
>   linux-image-generic. If you are using an older version of Ubuntu
>   Server, see explanation below:
>
> The linux-image-server package is a meta package that will install the
>   latest Server kernel version, while the linux-image-generic package is
>   a meta package for the latest Desktop kernel version. The server guide
>   includes some details on the changes made in the Server kernel.
>
> linux-image-server is used for both architectures x86 and amd64.
>
> Which one you should use will depend on the type of system you have.
>   If you have a 64 bit processor you can use the amd64 architecture, or
>   the x86 architecture. However, if your processor is 32 bit you can
>   only use the x86 kernel.

Comment: Thank you, that FAQ will probably answer some other questions I have!